# django How get creator username instead id using two for

Tags: django, django-users

I want get creator username instead id.
The `item.r.username` dont work.
`item.r.bornplace` work correctly.
Where i do mistake?

My model.py:

```
class Rec(models.Model):
        creator = models.ForeignKey(auth.get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        bornplace = models.CharField(default='default')
```

My views.py

```
def lists(request):
        list = Rec.objects.all()
        lists = []
        for r in list:
                lists.append({'r':r})
        context = {'lists': lists}
        return render(request, 'lists.html', context)
```

My lists.html

```
{% for item in lists %}
        {{ item.r.username }}
        {{ item.r.author_id }}
        {{ item.r.bornplace }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You define `bornplace`, you don't define `username` in your model, where is that coming from? Perhaps `item.r.creator.username`

Comment: @ViaTech ```item.r.creator.username``` work correctly. Simple but i was lost.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue you should use the Foreign Key mapping in the model fields you have defined from `creator` as defined below:

```
class Rec(models.Model):
    ...
    creator = models.ForeignKey(auth.get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In this instance I can see you are using Django's auth, and without going into too much detail their default model stores `username`, so from that your `username` attr can be accessed from your `creator` instance. With that, overall your template call should have been:

`{{ item.r.creator.username }}`

But this idea is not specific to Django's auth system, for all FK relationships defined in your models you can use the standard syntax to access fields as needed, both in `templates` and in `views`.

Models have attributes so use nested access to gather the values you need. For example:

`model.FKField.field` or `model.FKField.method()`

Naturally in templates there are no parentheses, so for using a method in a template the syntax is:

`{{ model.FKField.method }}`

Answer (score 0):

you should do it in this way:

```
{{ item.r.creator.username }}
```

Comment: This answer was posted between ViaTech's comment and answer, but lacks explanation.